# undo react native commands

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

i wanted to export my apk from react native ( 2 or 3 times successfully exported) and last time i faced an error and was from word spell but i thought it was react native problem so i decided to search and come up with some solutions and one of them was this

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js -- 
bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest 
android/app/src/main/res
```

so after running this i find out that what was my problem and fixed it but i getting a new error that says

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' duplicate resources
```

now i really want to undo the code above ... is this possible? or should i start a new project and move all codes and assets to new project?

react-native version : 0.57
i just really want to undo that code so its so important if there is a way! 
thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to undo other than delete the generated source bundles under the `bundle-output` path

Comment: have you cleaned your project ? just delete build folder inside app folder

Comment: @cricket_007  yea i've done rebuild and clear and didn't work at all i just want to fix that error and i think this is possible by undoing the code i just ran

Comment: Basically, your error is saying `duplicate resources`, and that means somewhere in your `res/` android folder, you have some file or ID that is repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved by moving all assets and components to new project and ran it all over again
Thats the only way worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In your android folder

- Execute `gradlew clean`
- Delete your build folder

And try again.

You do not need to redefine the cli options as `bundle-output` and `assets-dest` in react native nowadays.

Comment: did that and get that error again Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'. i know i dont need to redefine and i made a mistake now i want to undo it... is there a way?